# How to avoid purchasing Faulty "Cougar Point" Chipset motherboard?

Tags: intel-core-i7, chipset, sandy-bridge

I plan on purchasing an Intel 2600K processor and am worried about my motherboard choice considering the faulty chipset ("Cougar Point" Chipset ) issues.

What should I check to make sure I don't land up buying a faulty board?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to look for a board that is identified as having "B3 Stepping" for the chip-set.  Sometimes listed as a "Rev. B3" and sometimes there will be an "Intel Revised" logo, depends on the motherboard manufacturer for the most part, but they all tried pretty hard to ensure it was obvious that it had it.

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can help you identify it on a running system.

Asus has some good info [here](http://event.asus.com/2011/mb/Identify_B3_Motherboards/).

Comment: Also, none of the faulty boards should be generally available in retail channels anymore if you're buying new.

Comment: Ditto what afrazier said. Unless you're buying from an ebay shop run out of a third world country, it's highly unlikely you'll find any faulty cougar point boards in mainstream or even discount retail channels. Most boards names contain "B3" or "3" in them indicating they are the version replacing the faulty ones.

Comment: Exactly, relatively few of the broken ones made it out in the first place, and Intel was pretty darned fast about replacing them in the channel. :)